# Class which inherits from one base and many interfaces

Tags: c#

Quick question: In c# can one class implement one base class and many interfaces?

for example

```
public MyCar : CarBase, ICar, ISomething
{
   ...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: yes this is fine, as long as the class and/or baseclass implements whatever all the interfaces declares.

Comment: yes absolutely you can do use this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes this is fine, as long as the class and/or baseclass implements whatever all the interfaces declares.

Comment: thanks. should I follow naming convention ClassBase like CarBase or not ?

Comment: I would say no, do not use suffixes such as "Base".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this.

Here is good article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx